# Kafka streams window batching

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Coming from a Spark Streaming background - getting a grasp on Kafka streams.

I have a simple Spark Streaming application that reads from Kafka,

and returns the latest event per user in that minute

Sample events would look like `{"user": 1, "timestamp": "2018-05-18T16:56:30.754Z", "count": 3}, {"user": 1, "timestamp": "2018-05-22T16:56:39.754Z", "count": 4}`

I'm interested in how this would work in Kafka Streams, as it seems that there is an output for each event - when my use case is to reduce the traffic.

From my reading so far it seems that this is not straight forward, and you would have to use the processor api.

Ideally I would like to use the DSL instead of the processor API, as I am just starting to look at Kafka streams, but it seems that I would have to use the processor API's `punctuate` method to read from a state store every n seconds?

I'm using kafka 0.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At DSL level, Kafka Streams allows to configure KTable caches (enabled by default) that reduce downstream load. The cache is an LRU cache that is flushed regularly. Thus, while the cache reduces downstream load, it does not guarantee how many outputs per window you get. (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html)

If you strictly need a single output per window, using the Processor API is the right way to go.

Comment: Ah I see, is it reasonable to combine the processor API with the DSL? To use the DSL for reducing to latest event per user, and using the processor API's punctuate to trigger the output?

Comment: Yes. Cf: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration

Comment: Thank you for link! Do you think that ksql is a better choice for simple aggregations rather than streams? I'm happy to create another question if you believe that this is off topic.

Comment: I love KSQL (but I might be biased...). KSQL internally uses Kafka Streams as it's runtime -- thus, you would see the same behavior. There are plans to allow for single emit per window but this is not available atm. Thus, for now, you might be better off with using Streams API. Having said this: It's a "philosophical" question, but do you really need a single output per window??? Ofter people think they need because they are used to this model, but it's actually not a requirement. Just something to think about.

Comment: Ksql seems really cool to get up and running fast. I suppose the single output per window comes from my experience with spark streaming - guess I have to adjust my thinking! If you wanted the latest info, could you query the ktable via rest API? I see documentation for the rest API, is this a good use case? We do a count based on the latest events, and push the minutely data to a DB.

Comment: At KSQL level, the REST API can only be used to submit queries. "Interactive Queries" is not yet supported by KSQL. To use "Interactive Queries" it would be required to use Kafka Streams.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but Kafka Streams now supports `suppress` operation. Take a look [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/):

> You can use Suppress to effectively rate-limit just one KTable output
> or callback. Or, especially valuable for non-retractable outputs like
> alerts, you can use it to get only the final results of a windowed
> aggregation. The clearest use case for Suppress at the moment is
> getting final results

Based on the article, the code can look like:

```
events
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(
    TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(2).withGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
  )
  .count(Materialized.as("count-metric"))
  .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowClose(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
  .filter( _ < 4 )
  .toStream()
  .foreach( /* Send that email! */)
```

I'm using Kafka Streams 2.6.0 and I'm able to reuse the same approach to build a stream.